# Error Initializing std::array<card,52> for deck of cards

Tags: c++, oop, object, playing-cards

I am building a texas holdem game as a project to help learn OOP.  I built tictactoe multiple times with a single class and decided to move on to something a bit more challenging with classes/structs interacting with each other.  I am attempting to simply initialize my deck of cards from my `DeckOfCards` class in my constructor and I am receiving a syntax error.  Not sure what i'm doing wrong.  Any thoughts?

**The error is occurring in the `DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards() :` initialization**

**Receiving an error on each Diamonds, Values which says Symbol "Diamonds" could not be resolved, Symbol "Two" could not be resolved..etc..etc**

**DeckOfCards.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DeckOfCards.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include <array>


DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards()
:
    cards_(
        {Diamonds, Two},
        {Diamonds, Three},
        {Diamonds, Four},
        {Diamonds, Five},
        {Diamonds, Six},
        {Diamonds, Seven},
        {Diamonds, Eight},
        {Diamonds, Nine},
        {Diamonds, Ten},
        {Diamonds, Jack},
        {Diamonds, Queen},
        {Diamonds, King},
        {Diamonds, Ace})
{

}
```

**DeckOfCards.h**

```
* DeckOfCards.h
 *
 * 
 *      
 */

#ifndef DECKOFCARDS_H_
#define DECKOFCARDS_H_

#include <array>

class DeckOfCards
{

    public:
        DeckOfCards();

    private:
        std::array<Card,52> cards_;


};

#endif /* DECKOFCARDS_H_ */
```

**Card.h**

```
* Cards.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 8, 2016
 *      Author: TAmend
 */

#ifndef CARD_H_
#define CARD_H_

struct Card
{

    enum Suit_Type
    {
        Diamonds,
        Hearts,
        Spades,
        Clubs,
    } suit;

    enum Value_Type
    {

        Two = 2,
        Three = 3,
        Four = 4,
        Five = 5,
        Six = 6,
        Seven = 7,
        Eight = 8,
        Nine = 9,
        Ten = 10,
        Jack = 11,
        Queen = 12,
        King = 13,
        Ace = 14
    } value;

    void printCard();
};



#endif /* CARD_H_ */
```

Comment: It is helpful to include the actual error.

Comment: Write `cards_{{Diamonds, Two},....}`

Comment: I did that @πάνταῥεῖ still same errors =[

Comment: `{Card::Diamonds, Card::Two}`...

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That fixed it!  Makes sense actually that you'd have to reference the Card Class.  Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using a `typedef` for the *Deck Of Cards* rather than a class.  One less level of complication.

Answer (score 1):

`Suit_Type` and `Value_Type` are members of `Card`.  You need to qualify their values:

```
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards()
:
    cards_(
        {Card::Diamonds, Card::Two},
        {Card::Diamonds, Card::Three},
        {Card::Diamonds, Card::Four},
        {Card::Diamonds, Card::Five},
```

or move the enums to global scope.